# Why do I use 'if i == len(self.clients) -1' to check if it's the last iteration of the loop?

Tags: python, indexing

```
class Bank:
    def __init__(self, name, clients):
        self.name = name
        self.clients = clients
        
    def add_client(self, new_client):
        self.clients.append(new_client)
        return f"Client {new_client} added; \nList of clients updated: {self.clients}."
    
    def show_clients(self):
        if self.clients:
            print(f"List of clients:")
            for i, client in enumerate(self.clients):
                print(client)
                # IN HERE:
                if i == len(self.clients) -1:
                    return
        else:
            print(f"There are no clients registered at the bank.")
```

I'm trying to understand how this expression works on my code, and why can't I just use:

```
if i == len(self.clients[-1]):
    return
```

Comment: I assume you mean `if i == len(self.clients[0 : -1]): return`, in which case the answer is that it's much faster and much less wasteful to perform a single operation of simple arithmetic than to create an entirely new list.

Comment: FWIW, that if statement and included `return` are pointless. There will be no change to the behavior of the program if you remove it, because the `return` would only be executed at the end of the loop, and there aren't any statements to run after that loop ends anyway

Comment: But you **can** use *if i == len(self.clients[-1]):* if you want to. It won't necessarily do what you expect but you **can** do it. As an aside, you might want to check that the value of *clients* passed to your \_\_init__ function supports *append()*. As it stands you could do this: *Bank('Joe', 99)* and you would only discover the error of your ways if you invoke either of *add_client()* or *show_clients()*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is used to index here, and enumerate indexes starting from `0`. The length of the list is counted starting from `1` (i.e., first element) so naturally the last element will have the index `length - 1`.

`self.clients[-1]` returns the last element of the array so `i == len(self.clients[-1])` checks if the length of the last element is the same as `i` which is not the same thing.

if you have the following, len(the_list[-1])`will return`5`:

```py
# a, b, c = something
d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
the_list = [a, b, c, d]
```